# is it possible to send the output of layer in CNN to several layer that works in parallel and group convolution node?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, keras-layer

I am a beginner in Keras and maybe my question will be simple, but I need your answers. suppose I have a CNN. usually, we send the output of layer as an input to the next layer. now, I want to know is it possible to send the output of one layer to several layers with different kernel size and then concatenate the output of them and send it to the next layer. this means I have some conv2d that are beside each other with different kernel size and the output of prior layer is fed to each of them and then the output of all conv2d concatenated to each other and send to next layer. is it possible? if yes how can I do it? Thank you.
[an example of my structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xH2jC.png)

Comment: It is possible to pass data to multiple parallel layers; however, you will run into problems during the combination of the parallel outputs. Convolutions with different kernels will produce different output sizes, so in order to properly combine them you will have to introduce an intermediate step to match the output sizes.

Comment: What you described is the Inception Module: https://arxiv.org/abs/1409.4842

Comment: I want to use same padding so the output of them will be the same. I did not see inception module before, but yes I like something like this. could you please tell me how can I implement a network with this structure?

Comment: sorry, could you please help me or give me a sample code or link?